# Joomla URL re-write urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla

I am trying to get the URL-rewriting working and so have changed the htaccess.txt to .htaccess, and turned URL re-writing on. I can see the htaccess change worked fine, because it originally complained about php versions and so I needed to include a line from my old htaccess in there.

My aim was to get rid of the /index.php?/ part from the URL.

However, my URLs now look like this:

http://thesite.co.uk/websites/123reg/LinuxPackage25/th/e/si/te/thesite.co.uk/public_html/problem-behaviours

This is a link to just a normal article. Ideally, this should be:
http://thesite.co.uk/problem-behaviours.

It seems to do this for all articles, any ideas why?
My htaccess file is below:

```
    AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5

##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2014 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: which joomla version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Remove line `AddType application/x-httpd-php55 .php .php5` From htaccess and change the configuration setting from admin.

[image: Change the setting from Global configuration section]

Comment: That first line has to be there else I get an error message saying that it using an older version of php and the pages don't load at all. The SEO settings I already have turned on. In the .htcaccess file, it turns out I needed to uncomment:
RewriteBase /

Answer (score 0):

The final solution was that in the .htaccess file, the `RewriteBase /` needed uncommenting.
Tutorials online didn't point to that.

```
    ##
    # Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
    # is not directly related to physical file paths.
    # Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
    ##

RewriteBase /
```